# What does this command line that starts with "1, $" do in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a shell script created by someone else which I am currently trying to understand and there is a line in it which is

```
vim -c "1,\$s/MAJOR_VERSION = ./MAJOR_VERSION = $1/" -c "1,\$s/MINOR_VERSION = .*/MINOR_VERSION = $2/" -c "wq" $f
```

I know what it does is change `MAJOR_VERSION = .` to my input (`$1`), but I don't understand what the

```
"1, \$s
```

at the beginning means. The corresponding vim command from terminal would be
`:\s/MAJOR_VERSION...` etc, so what does the $s do in this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`1,$` defines the range on which your substitute command `s/../../` is applied. `1,$` means 'from the first to the last line'. See [`:help range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange) in Vim for more.

Comment: ... and it's escaped in this context to prevent the shell from expanding `$s` as a shell variable

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that you can use `%` as shorthand for `1,$`.